# Outlook365: How to automatically have all replies I make in plain text?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I receive emails in all formats (html, text, rich text). Every time I reply, I want the reply to be quoted, plain text.

My typical workflow in Outlook365 is to select the text I want to quote, and then use the Quote option to pass that text into the reply.

However, because I reply in line (or because how I do replies), I need the reply to be in plain text.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want the entire message to be in plain text? Or do you want just the quote to be stripped of all non-standard text components?

Comment: @Appleoddity OP enhanced, thank you for pointing that out.